# Dynamic blaze template with dynamic data not working

Tags: jquery, templates, meteor, materialize, meteor-blaze

I am developing an app using Meteor-1.6+Blaze+materialize and create a multiple modal template for example aModal, bModal, cModal..etc and calling these template into main template on buttons click using ReactiveVar.

```
this.modalTemplate = new ReactiveVar(false);
this.modalData = new ReactiveVar({});

{{> Template.dynamic template=getModalTemplate data=getModalData }}
```

DynamicModalTemplate & modalData are helpers that provide dynamically selected modal template and data for modal.

Helpers:

```
getModalTemplate() {
        return Template.instance().modalTemplate.get() || '';
    },
getModalData () {
        return Template.instance().modalData.get() || '';
    }
```

Events:

```
'click #carModalTrigger' (event, inst) {        
        import ('./cars.js').then(() => {
            inst.modalTemplate.set("carsModal");
            Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
                $("#carsModal").modal();
                $("#carsModal").modal('open');
            }, 200)
        });
    },

    'click #brandingSectionTrigger' (event, inst) {
        import ('./bikes.js').then(() => {

            inst.modalTemplate.set("bikeModal");
            Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
                $("#brandingSection").modal();
                $("#brandingSection").modal('open');
            }, 200)
        });
    }
```

Setting Modal Data variable:

```
this.autorun(() => {
            const dataHandle = Meteor.subscribe('myCollection');

            if (dataHandle.ready()) {
                console.log("==> SubsReady ::: ", dataHandle);
                let vData = {};
                vData = MyCollection.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).fetch();
                  this.modalData.set(vData);
                  console.log("=> vData ",vData)
                }
            }
    }
```

modalData is updating dynamically but modal showing old data, like when i open cars modal it showing correct data but after closing it if modalData is updated and i again open cars modal it showing me old data not updated one.

It showing updated data when i open Bikes modal and close it, now again open Cars modal will displaying updated data.

Please guide me how i can load updated data whenever i open the modal.

Thanks.

Comment: Where/when do you set the modalData ReactiveVar?

Comment: @bordalix I am setting modalData inside Template onCreated under this.autorun, inside autorun i am doing subscription and loading data into modalData variable. So it load dynamic data and it's working correctly as i console out the variable, it's showing updated data.

Comment: Can you show the code where you do that?

Comment: @bordalix i have added code to load data into modalData reactiveVar in question.

Comment: First of all, you're putting your user in the modalData reactive var, not your modal data. Second, your autorun code is not reactive, it only runs once. You should put some dependency on it that you know will change across time, in order to force the code to re-run. Something like this: modalTemplate = this.modalTemplate.get(); vData = MyCollection.find({template: modalTemplate }).fetch(); This way, every time the modalTemplate changes, your autorun code will run again.

Comment: @bordalix Thank You, now it's working :)

Comment: I did something similar but for bootstrap here: [MasterModal](https://github.com/robertdavid010/meteor_bootstrap-master-modal). In my approach I make sure to clear the modal template when the modal is closed, this will make sure whatever modal template you load next, will have the first run.